# JavaFX circular radial gradial radient in half circle

Tags: javafx, gradient, shapes, circular-dependency, intersect

I need to add a circular radial gradient to a subtracted circle. I have been trying but I cannot get a circular gradient.

[image: Circular radial gradient trial]

1: Whole circle
2: Radial gradient in whole circle
3: Subtracted circle
4: Circular radial gradient trial in subtracted circle (not what I want)
5: Circular radial gradient in subtracted circle. **This is what I want to obtain.**

Once I get the subtracted circle (3), I apply the radial gradient but I get (4) instead of (5).

```
int x = 0.5;
int y = 0.5;

RadialGradient gradientCut = new RadialGradient(0, 0, x, y, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new 
Stop[] {
            new Stop(0, Color.ORANGE),
            new Stop(0.2, Color.YELLOW),
            new Stop(0.5, Color.TRANSPARENT)
});

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 75);

Shape cutCircleGradient = Shape.intersect(circleGradientCut, rect);
cutCircleGradient.setFill(gradientCut);
```

I also tried changing values x and y but I'm not getting what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use clip to slice your circle:

```
double x = 0.5;
double y = 0.5;

RadialGradient gradientCut = new RadialGradient(0, 0, x, y, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new
        Stop[]{
        new Stop(0, Color.ORANGE),
        new Stop(0.2, Color.YELLOW),
        new Stop(0.5, Color.TRANSPARENT)
});
double radius = 50.0;
Circle c = new Circle(radius, gradientCut);
var clip = new Rectangle(radius * 2, radius);
clip.setTranslateX(-radius);
clip.setTranslateY(-65);
//clip.setTranslateY(-50);  --> half circle
c.setClip(clip);
```